# SequenceMatcher - prefer ordered matching

Tags: python

I have a `SequenceMatcher` function to find closest match given:

- string
- a list of strings

code:

```
def seq_match(text, values, min_match=10):
    highest = (None, 0)
    for v in values:
        sm = SequenceMatcher(a=text, b=v, autojunk=False)
        ratio = int(sm.quick_ratio() * 100)
        print(f'{text} : {v} : {ratio}')
        if ratio > min_match and ratio > highest[1]:
            highest = v, ratio
    return highest
```

I also have a data set:

```
# (text, value1, value2, value3...): expected_output
test_map = {
    # 1
    ('super delicious cat food', 'decent', 'delicious', 'super delicious'): 'super delicious',
    # 2
    ('salmon: does not contain real salmon', 'chicken', 'salmon', 'arctic salmon'): 'arctic salmon',
}
```

And while `#1` data is being matched correctly the `#2` match assumes that the longer string `artic salmon` is a better match than just `salmon`.
In other words I expect `salmon` to be a better match to equal or greater mathan `artic salmon`.

Here are all match results:

```
# correct 
super delicious cat food : decent : 33
super delicious cat food : delicious : 54
super delicious cat food : super delicious : 76
salmon: does not contain real salmon : chicken : 18
salmon: does not contain real salmon : salmon : 28
# incorrect
salmon: does not contain real salmon : arctic salmon : 48 
# expected
salmon: does not contain real salmon : arctic salmon : 28 or less
```

Can I force `SequenceMatcher` act more sanely here? How could I get results that I want? Why does `arctic` even produce score?

I've tried turning off automatic junk but it doesn't seem to have an affect.

Comment: did you try using `sm.ratio()` instead of `sm.quick_ratio()`?

Comment: @eladm26 yeah, same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the doc of `SequenceMatcher` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher)

you will see the following description of its algorithm:

```
The idea is to find the longest contiguous matching subsequence that contains   
no “junk” elements
```

In light of this definition it makes sense that `arctic salmon` will get a higher similarity score that `salmon`.
To better understand why look at the following code:

```
a = 'salmon: does not contain real salmon'
b = 'arctic salmon'
sm = SequenceMatcher(a, b, autojunk=False)  
sm.get_matching_blocks()
```

output:

```
[Match(a=1, b=0, size=1),
 Match(a=15, b=3, size=1),
 Match(a=17, b=5, size=1),
 Match(a=29, b=6, size=7),
 Match(a=36, b=13, size=0)]
```

as you can see there are 10 matches for `arctic salmon` comparing to only 6 of `salmon` which gives you a rate of `2 * 10 / 49 = 0.40816326530612246`.
For a complete explanation of `ratio()` calculation loot at the link above.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. That's how I understood it works as well but was not aware of the `get_matching_blocks` method! It's very weird that it considers size=1 matches worthy enough for raising the score so much for matching 1 letter. Nevertheless I can pick it up from where and implement my own ratio method that discards small size matches, thanks!